# Can someone walk me through this code (assembly)?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, msp430

I am playing around with an MSP430 Microcontroller and I am trying to understand how to get different physical components to talk with each other. In this case I have the code (from a friend) that  uses a dip switch to turn on different segments of an 7 segment LED display. I am trying to read through this code and understand how it works, and what registers are in play.

```
; Author:
; Date:
; Title:
;
#include "msp430.h"                     ; #define controlled include file
;
; This is a basic template for the MSP430(G2231).
; The I2C.r43 library should be linked into this build to resolve references
; to the subroutines defined as EXTERN below.
;
RESET   EQU     0FFFEh
RAM     EQU     00200h
FLASH   EQU     0F800h
;
; The possible "Address" values to be passed into the subroutines below.
;
I2C_0   EQU     00000000b   // A2-A0: 000 ;Switches
I2C_1   EQU     00000010b   // A2-A0: 001
I2C_2   EQU     00000100b   // A2-A0: 010
I2C_3   EQU     00000110b   // A2-A0: 011 ;LEDs
I2C_4   EQU     00001000b   // A2-A0: 100
I2C_5   EQU     00001010b   // A2-A0: 101
I2C_6   EQU     00001100b   // A2-A0: 110
I2C_7   EQU     00001110b   // A2-A0: 111
;
; Routines below come from external I2C module
;
; No parameters
        EXTERN  InitI2C  
; Address in R12 (just A3-A1 required) - A2-A0 pins left-shifted one
; On return:  R12 = 1 if A part exists, R12 = 2 if _ part exists, R12 = 0 if no device
        EXTERN  ChkI2C        
; Address in R12 (just A3-A1 required) - A2-A0 pins left-shifted one
; Data to output in R13
        EXTERN  OutI2C        
; Address in R12 (just A3-A1 required) - A2-A0 pins left-shifted one
; Data received in R12 on return
        EXTERN  InI2C

        PUBLIC  main

        ORG     RESET
        DC16    init                    ; Set reset vector to 'init' label

        ORG     RAM

        ; <declare any global variables here>

        ORG     FLASH

init:   mov     #0280h, SP              ; Set up stack pointer
        mov     #WDTPW+WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer

main:   ; <insert additional program code here>

      mov.w #0x5A80, &WDTCTL
      call #InitI2C
      clr.w R12
      call #InI2C
      mov.w R12, R13
      mov.w #0x6, R12
      call #OutI2C
      jmp main 

        END
```

I am having a very tough time understanding various parts of the code. For example:

Do we really need this line:

```
mov.w #0x5A80, &WDTCTL
```

in main? How about the `6` being moved into `R13`? Why is it `6` and not any other number? I also feel as though the main section can be simplified alot more than what it currently is.

If someone can help run me through this code? I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is something read from I2C into R12, this is moved to R13 and send to output I2C from register R13 (it is done in subroutines defined somewhere else - EXTERN).

Don't know why is in main loop Init, but maybe someone will say.

Number 6 is addressing of I2C module, as it is written in comments up.

If you have other questions, just ask.

Comment: Thanks you for the relatively quick response.Something is read from I2C and placed into R12. When I ran this code in the debugger, R12 contained the hex value FF after the InI2C subroutine was called. Any significance to the value FF?

As for the number 6, does that refer to the specific I2C expander if more than one is used?

Comment: I'm not sure, if debugger emulates I2C (if you are not running on real microcontroller). I don't have any emulator to test it.
Number 6 can refer to I2C_6 constant, as I read it again, which should be the code displayed, but I can be wrong ...

Comment: It looks like this code doesnt target specific segments of the LED to be turned on by specific switches. Or does it? What would it look like if i wanted to turn on specific segments on the LED?

Comment: It depends how is this display connected and what is it's communication interface.

Comment: (sorry, I pressed enter so early)
But in this code, it looks like it is connected to I2C bus and the number is not addressed of specific led segments, but just binary number and it is decoded by the display in pins A3 to A1.
The first line is watchdog configuration and it should be totaly done before the loop (it is I think the same as row above, but in binary (I don't want to look for binary representation, but you can google it somewhere).

Comment: heres a link to the diagram:
http://www.uccs.edu/~mlaubhan/ece3420/ECE3420BreadBoardSchematic.jpg